# Padding before or after truncation for stateful LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, lstm, rnn

I am training an LSTM on a dataset with variable timesteps (between 10 and 6000). Using the truncated backpropagation through time (TBPTT) technique, I am truncating the sequences to windows of 128 timesteps. Hence, sequences will have between 1 and 47 windows.

There are two possible ways I think I can do this.

One way is I can first pad all sequences with zeros (post-padding) to the 6000th timestep, and then truncate each sequence to 47 windows. Then, I can train a stateful LSTM on each window, resetting the LSTM state after all 47 windows:

```
def pad_and_truncate(X_batch, num_windows=47, windowlen=128, padvalue=0):
    X_padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
                                        X_batch, 
                                        maxlen= num_windows * windowlen,
                                        dtype='int32',
                                        padding='post',
                                        value=padvalue)
    X_truncated = [X_padded[:, i*windowlen : (i+1)*windowlen] \
                   for i in range(num_windows)]
        
    return X_truncated


for batch in range(batches):
    X_batch, y_batch = getBatch(data, batch, batch_size) # Split entire dataset into batches
    X_truncated = pad_and_truncate(X_batch, num_windows=47, 
                                   windowlen=128, padvalue=0)

    assert len(X_truncated) == 47

    for window in range(len(X_truncated)):
        model.fit(X_truncated[window], y_batch, batch_size=batch_size)
    model.reset_states()
```

Alternatively, I can first truncate each sequence to windows of size 128, and then only pad the last window with zeros. For example a sequence with 200 timesteps will be truncated to 2 windows (128 + 72 timesteps). Then, only the second window will be padded with 56 zeros (128 + 128 timesteps). Using this method, sequences will have varying window sizes (between 1 and 47), rather than all sequences having 47 windows as in the first method. The shortest sequence (10 timesteps) will only have 118 zeros padded to it rather than 6006 zeros.

```
for batch in range(batches):
    X_batch, y_batch = getBatch(data, batch, batch_size) # Split entire dataset into batches
    num_windows = np.ceil(X_batch.shape[0] / 128).astype(int)
    X_truncated = pad_and_truncate(X_batch, num_windows=num_windows,
                                   windowlen=128, padvalue=0)

    assert (1 <= len(X_truncated) <= 47)

    for window in range(len(X_truncated)):
        model.fit(X_truncated[window], y_batch, batch_size=batch_size)
    model.reset_states()
```

The first method (padding before truncation) seems very inefficient, since there will be a lot of zeros added to shorter sequences, and the second method (padding after truncation) seems more practical.

However, in a simple test with Keras LSTM models, the first method converged to a solution, though it was very slow (due to the larger number of windows). However, the second method did not converge at all despite the speed.

What would you suggest is the best way to apply TBPTT in dealing with very long sequences with keras LSTMs? Is there a more efficient way than padding all sequences to 6000 timesteps?